# Unstable checkstyle results between launches

Tags: java, maven, checkstyle

We were using checkstyle for our multi-module maven project quite for a long time. Recently I've customized our checkstyle configuration file to meet out needs more (some warnings were turned off, changed priority for others, etc.) - and strange things began. Now maven checkstyle plugin generates slightly different results from run to run. I.e. if you do `mvn clean install checkstyle:checkstyle` in the same module 10 times in a row, 8-9 of them results are the same, but 1-2 times there're several extra warnings missing before (though they are correct). And it seems like differences are coming from  `com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.checks.javadoc.JavadocStyleCheck` rule only...

The same problem remains with versions 2.10, 2.11 and 2.12.2 of maven-checkstyle-plugin.

Have anyone seen such a behavior? Any suggestions how to fix it?

Comment: Are you doing the 10 runs directly from the same command line? Or is some sort of build server involved? Are you sure maven didn't download anything new in between the runs?

Comment: First time noticed it from Jenkins statistics, but it is also reproduced from plain command line only. I.e. open terminal, do `mvn clean install checkstyle:checkstyle`, check _checkstyle-results.xml_ in the text editor, do `mvn clean install checkstyle:checkstyle`, check _checkstyle-results.xml_ in the text editor and so on.
Yes I'm pretty sure - no output from maven about any additional downloads and it also happens when using only local nexus that is not updated between runs.